# Is there a way to get seedgoose seed to work without manually entering all the data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, mongoose, command-line

I am trying to seed my database in a project in which I am running a website and am running into the following error when trying to run the command "npx seedgoose seed" through both Command Prompt and Windows PowerShell:

```html
C:\Users\mathe\travlr>npx seedgoose seed
C:\Users\mathe\travlr\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:707
      throw new MongooseError('Can\'t call `openUri()` on an active connection with ' +
            ^

MongooseError: Can't call `openUri()` on an active connection with different connection strings. Make sure you aren't calling `mongoose.connect()` multiple times. See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections
    at Connection.openUri (C:\Users\mathe\travlr\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:707:13)
    at C:\Users\mathe\travlr\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:351:10
    at C:\Users\mathe\travlr\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\mathe\travlr\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\mathe\travlr\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1149:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\mathe\travlr\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:350:20)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\mathe\travlr\app_server\database\models\db.js:10:31)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)

Node.js v18.9.0
```

I have installed mongoose and am able to install npm. I have tried looking up the solution online with no resolution and have tried deleting the package-lock.json file in my project with no effect. Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Mathew

Comment: does `C:\Users\mathe\travlr\app_server\database\models` exist?

Comment: Yes it does exist. I have edited my code because I am receiving a new error which is above.

Comment: `'${finalPath}'.` does look like an odd file name - perhaps your *code* is using that, instead of an actual path - you possibly are using `"` instead of `\`` somewhere in your *code* - does the string `${finalPath}` appear in your *code* somewhere? are you doing the right thing in your *code*

Comment: I have checked for '${finalPath}'. and am not finding it anywhere as well as checking for using " instead of ', but am using all the right things in my code as far as I can tell. Also, I am receiving a new error when running the same command, which I have edited above.

Comment: strange - 3 different errors but you've changed nothing

Comment: I just checked MongoDB Compass and it all of a sudden has popped up with the database that I needed and I don't know how.